# How can I see which packages will be updated from apt?

Tags: server, apt, updates

I see on my server at the login, that a few updates are available.

How can I see which packages will be updated on my server without starting the update?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the `--dry-run`, `-s`, `--simulate`, `--just-print`, `--recon`, `--no-act` argument and it won't actually do anything, it'll just tell you what it would do:

From the apt-get man page

```
-s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act
          No action; perform a simulation of events that would occur but do
          not actually change the system. Configuration Item:
          APT::Get::Simulate.

          Simulate prints out a series of lines each one representing a dpkg
          operation, Configure (Conf), Remove (Remv), Unpack (Inst). Square
          brackets indicate broken packages with and empty set of square
          brackets meaning breaks that are of no consequence (rare).
```

so easily take a look into the comand:

```
apt-get upgrade --dry-run
```

or

```
apt-get upgrade -s
```

Comment: What means the argument "--just-print"?

Comment: same as `--dry-run`

Comment: @Maythux --- no need to use sudo if you simulate. Safer ;-)